# VS2010 - "Unable to connect to a database specified in the solution"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Having migrated to Win 8.1, I am now getting this message box when building an existing project.

I cannot workout how to get rid of this box as I dont need this feature. Where is the setting that is making this box appear?

On build I get this message box.

```
Unable to connect to a database specified in the solution.
Do you want to modify this database connection properties?
```

[image]

I have inspected the SLN and PROJ files and cannot see the cause. In the solution it happens for some projects and cannot see a pattern as to why two projects that are similar where one is and one is not showing the box on build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `{Projectname}.csproj.user` file.
Remove the xml element

```
<DatabaseConnection></DatabaseConnection>
```

Then either restart VS to reload the project.
Or
Unload and reload the project from within the VS IDE.

*Since I was getting the box due to a dependant other project in the solution, it would be a good idea to do an inspection of all `csproj.user` files for the xml element.*